# What is type of these characters?

Tags: javascript

I cannot copy/paste it here because it doesn't show in this editor. I attach it as a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: These are non-printable control characters (`0x12` and `0x18` respectively). Looks like your script file has been seriously messed up.

Comment: As the variables are shortened I would guess it is the result of an aggressive code obfuscator. If this is a script on your page and you don't know where it is from, then you should check if it is malicious.